# Varying slopes in a mixed effects model and significance

Tags: regression, mixed-model, regression-coefficients

It seems wise to usually include random slopes in addition to the fixed slopes for lower level predictors as described in some previous questions:

[When should I *not* permit a fixed effect to vary across levels of a random effect in a mixed effects model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10002/when-should-i-not-permit-a-fixed-effect-to-vary-across-levels-of-a-random-effe)

[Varying group coefficients in lme4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14204/varying-group-coefficients-in-lme4)

My question is interpretation of the significance of the fixed effect when it is highly significant without letting the slopes vary but loses significance when the slopes do vary.

This predictor is obviously important but is it only important for certain upper level effects and should not be generalized to the population of interest?

Comment: Do you have a sense of whether having random slopes makes sense for the specific problem you are looking at? Sometimes I find thinking about what you are actually trying to model in real life is more important than the "technicalities" of the model itself...